# Unity How to play two videos synchronously

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

We are creating disparity videos with Unity.
What I would like to know is to synchronize and reproduce two different types of videos.

Currently, I prepare two movies for the right eye and two for the left eye and play it repeatedly.
In that case, the two videos may be misaligned.
The code is as follows.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movie_Script : MonoBehaviour {
    public MovieTexture movie_l;
    public MovieTexture movie_r;
    public Renderer renderer;
    void Start () {

        renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        movie_l = (MovieTexture)renderer.material.GetTexture("_Movie_L");
        movie_r = (MovieTexture)renderer.material.GetTexture("_Movie_R");

        movie_l.Play();
        movie_r.Play();          
    }
}
```

.

```
Shader "Unlit/Movie_sample"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Movie_L("Movie_Left", 2D) = "white"{}
        _Movie_R("Movie_Right", 2D) = "black"{}
    }
...
}
```

What else went.
Two movies are arranged side by side to make one movie, and when playing it, clip right and left to obtain two textures and then set them.
However, in this case, it seems that it takes time to convert Texture to Texture 2D, and it drops to about fps = 10 (the upper is about 60).

Comment: Maybe its better to combine the videos ahead of time, pre-split for each eye leading to a _single video_ rather than trying to play two at runtime?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
When dividing in advance, FPS slowed down.

Comment: That makes no sense

Answer (score 1):

I have some experience to sync videos, but I'm using **VideoPlayer**, prepare the videoPlayers before playing.

```
IEnumerator prepareVideo() {

   videoPlayer1.Prepare();
   videoPlayer2.Prepare();
   while (!videoPlayer1.isPrepared)
   {
       Debug.Log("Preparing Video 1");
       yield return null;
   }
   Debug.Log("Done Video 1");

   while (!videoPlayer2.isPrepared)
   {
       Debug.Log("Preparing Video 2");
       yield return null;
   }
   Debug.Log("Done Video 2");

   videoPlayer1.Play();
   videoPlayer2.Play();
}
```